# Coinbase + AWS Kinesis

Tags: data-analysis, amazon-kinesis, trading, coinbase-api, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I currently got the struggle that I don't know how to get the data from coinbase into Amazon Kinesis (Firehose) to analyse it their.

Through the coinbase API I set up a websocket that gives me a json file of the data. How do I pass this json into Kinesis? I know you have to use the putRecords() method but where and how do I implement this?

Am Thankful for every help, my thesis depends on it...